# Anyone recognizing or knowing how to solve this integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I would like to find closed-form (or, failing that, series) expressions for the following four integrals:

$$\int^X_0 \cos(a \cos(x)) \cos(b \sin(x)) dx$$

$$\int^X_0 \cos(a \cos(x)) \sin(b \sin(x)) dx$$

$$\int^X_0 \sin(a \cos(x)) \cos(b \sin(x)) dx$$

$$\int^X_0 \sin(a \cos(x)) \sin(b \sin(x)) dx$$

where $X = \pi$ or $2\pi$ and $a$, $b$ are constants. I cannot find them in tables, and the usual substitutions ($t=\tan(x/2)$, $t=\sin(x)$, $t=\cos(x)$) or use of sum/difference formulas for converting products/sums of trigonometric functions do not lead to 
recognizable forms either. Any leads? (NB: $a$ and $b$ are multidimensional parameters that need separate assignment and evaluation; also further nested integration is needed afterwards, so quadrature or statistical calculation methods are not feasible in my case.)

Comment: I doubt there is a simple solution...

Comment: what says Wolframalpha?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are distinct, not seeing anything closed form on first glance.  However, in the special case when $a$ and $b$ are near enough, so one can write $b = a + \epsilon$ ($|\epsilon|$ small), for the first integral you can look at the Taylor expansion
$$
\cos(b y) = \cos( [a + \epsilon] y) = \cos( a y) - \epsilon y \sin (ay) + \ldots, 
$$
with $y = \sin(x)$ and see if that gives a good approximation of the integral.

Alternatively (I haven't carefully analyzed this), I would also explore if complex analysis methods can get anywhere here.

Comment: @avs There aren't any poles, so one must be pretty creative to use complex analysis

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, true.  As I remarked, I didn't explore in detail, nor do I have time to.  Come to think of it, I would also try generally Taylor expansions.

Comment: @avs: unfortunately, a and b are not close in my case. But thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: Posted also on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271474/anyone-recognizing-or-knowing-how-to-solve-this-integral
I consider the advice given in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) very reasonable. Of course, you can have a look also at other discussions on [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Answer (score 3):

Applying trig. rules for the product of function, in each case one obtains sum of terms like $\cos(a\cos(x)+b\sin(x))$ (or sines, or with negative signs...).
They can be transformed into $\cos(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x-\phi))$. Now, integrating on $(0,2\pi)$ which is a period of the function one can drop the $\phi$ shift and obtain things like
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x))\,dx =2\pi J_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$$
If $X=\pi$, this should be halfed as the function to be integrated are even.

Comment: Clever, this transformation to single-term argument of cos.